# How can I control when iCloud syncs my core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, icloud

I have the following code in place to sync my core data with iCloud. I only want it to sync when I say, however. For example, to only sync when on wifi. Would I be able to do this? Here is my code:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
            [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
        }];
        managedObjectContext = moc;

        managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = [[NSMergePolicy alloc]
                                            initWithMergeType:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType];
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Merging in changes from iCloud...");

    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];

    [moc performBlock:^{

        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

        NSNotification* refreshNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"SomethingChanged"
                                                                            object:self
                                                                          userInfo:[notification userInfo]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:refreshNotification];
    }];
}
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EntryDatabase" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if((persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // Set up iCloud in another thread:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you MUST change this variable:
        NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"iCloud ID is here, i removed it from stack overflow";

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you should change this variable:
        NSString *dataFileName = @"CoreDataStore.sqlite";

        // ** Note: For basic usage you shouldn't need to change anything else

        NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data.nosync";
        NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

        NSURL *localStore = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];

        NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

        if (iCloud) {

            NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

            NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

            NSLog(@"iCloudEnabledAppID = %@",iCloudEnabledAppID);
            NSLog(@"dataFileName = %@", dataFileName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudDataDirectoryName = %@", iCloudDataDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsDirectoryName = %@", iCloudLogsDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloud = %@", iCloud);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsPath = %@", iCloudLogsPath);

            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]] == NO) {
                NSError *fileSystemError;
                [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                        attributes:nil
                                             error:&fileSystemError];
                if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error creating database directory %@", fileSystemError);
                }
            }

            NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path]
                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

            NSLog(@"iCloudData = %@", iCloudData);

            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
            [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

            [psc lock];

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData]
                                    options:options
                                      error:nil];

            [psc unlock];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"iCloud is NOT working - using a local store");
            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

            [psc lock];

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:localStore
                                    options:options
                                      error:nil];
            [psc unlock];

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged" object:self userInfo:nil];
        });
    });

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;

 }
```

Comment: Ensembles (http://ensembles.io) is a framework that I develop for syncing Core Data. It gives you control over when you sync, and will also automatically migrate and merge existing data.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can tell, this can't happen. Not in any simple and efficient manner anyway.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html

The problem is that the operations of iCloud are not transparent. Thus iOS decides when a sync will occur and how often. in the document above, Apple says that "best practice" is to use the sandbox exclusively or the iCloud exclusively, but don't copy your data between them.

That said, apple makes a reference to operating when iCloud becomes unavailable. This seems to fit the scenario that you are suggesting. Fundamentally, you would need to set it up as normal, ensure you have the data you need, then deactivate iCloud and move your data to the sandbox to work on it. When you want to sync, you just copy the data back.

> To handle changes in iCloud availability, implement a method to be invoked on receiving an NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification notification. Your method needs to perform the following work:
>
> Call the ubiquityIdentityToken method and store its return value.
> Compare the new value to the previous value, to find out if the user signed out of their account or signed in to a different account.
> If the previously-used account is now unavailable, save the current state locally as needed, empty your iCloud-related data caches, and refresh all iCloud-related user interface elements.
> If you want to allow users to continue creating content with iCloud unavailable, store that content in your app’s sandbox container. When the account is again available, move the new content to iCloud. It’s usually best to do this without notifying the user or requiring any interaction from the user.

This would seem to match your requirements. However, I am only just reaching this stage myself, so I cannot comment further.